# Reload "Mail.App" UIAlert with Swift in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, email, uialertcontroller

As you knew, Apple allowing remove the some default apps in iOS 10. One of them is "Mail.app". If "Mail.app" is not installed and app trying handle a "mailto:" url, it shows a info alert like this:

[image: Mail.app alert]

What I want to ask is,

***- It is a alert which popped from automatically from iOS system ?***

OR

***- A custom alert which coded by app developer ?***

I can control "mailto:" url handle capability with SharedApplication.

How can I show such a warning if the system is not showing up?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand the question, but is it MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail you are looking for?

Comment: I think you can look at your app state to answer the first question. If it's inactive, the alert should be a system alert.

Comment: The URL schemes are managed by the system. You can only check: your application can be open the url or not. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl

Comment: @Grundwaldeatsacoelacanth, Thanks for support. I'm using MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail already. My question is; how can I pop an alert which like on the screenshot (Download in App Store)?

Comment: @Mannopson I check canOpenURL with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes requirement ("mailto:" added). The alert described on the screenshot seems a system alert ("Download in App Store"). How can I handle this alert ?

Comment: @Andreas How can I handle(show) a system alert ?

Comment: Please show your code! How to access the mail compose view controller?

Comment: func sendEmail() {
   if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mail.setToRecipients(["ved.ios@yopmail.com"])
    mail.setMessageBody("<p>You're so awesome!</p>", isHTML: true)

    present(mail, animated: true)
    } else {
    // URL check
   }
 }

Comment: Nothing wrong! Don't worry about it! The system itself responsible for it. Because all of the data still stored on the device, if the user used before the mail app. The iOS only deletes the visibility of the mail app from the home screen not data. Therefore system itself shows the same type of messages and alerts.

Comment: @Mannopson Thanks :) If I use MFMailComposeViewController without canSendMail(), iOS shows "No Mail Account" alert automatically. No "App Store" alert thrown, however I though it is caused from the emulator (It have not any App Store.).